# AngularJS View-Model creation on Server or Client?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, join

I am curious how others are creating their AngularJS view-models using an underlying relational database?  My team and I are having trouble deciding if we should make object joins on the server-side or the client-side.

For example, we have a couple models on the server like `Author`, `Book`, and `BookComment`. In the first example, there is just a single endpoint to GET an `Author` like `/api/author/:id` and it "packages" up the entire view-model on the server. The second example, each object has their own RESTful API endpoint like `/api/authors/:id`, `api/books/:id` and `/api/bookcomments/:id`.

An `Author` can have 1 or more `Book` objects and a `Book` can have 1 or more `BookComment` objects.

Now lets compare the 2 scenarios:

**Server-side Join**

We let the server join the objects based off of foreign keys and end up with an object like

**Author**

```
           {
                'id':1,
                'firstName':'John',
                'lastName':'Steinbeck',
                'books':[{
                   'id':123,
                   'title': 'Grapes of Wrath',
                   'author':1,
                   'comments':[{
                       'id':555,
                       'content':'This is a great book!',
                       'book':123
                   }]
                }]
            }
```

This  gets ALL of the needed data and objects to render the view correctly.  The problem then becomes managing the comments and books at an atomic level, so if the user only edits a comment, we don't want to save the entire `Author` object, but rather just update the `BookComment` object.  This would require pulling out the objects and bootstrapping them with an Angular `$resource` or something similar.

**Client-side Join**

We ask for the models individually and then join them on the client:

**Author**

```
        {
            'id':1,
            'firstName':'John',
            'lastName':'Steinbeck',
            'books':[]
        }
```

**Book**

```
        {
            'id':123,
            'title': 'Grapes of Wrath',
            'author':1,
            'comments':[]
        }
```

**BookComment**

```
         {
              'id':555,
              'content':'This is a great book!',
              'book':123
         }
```

If I pull down the lists of objects using a RESTful interface, then I can join them using something like

```
//Get the author
var author = Author.get();

//Join the books that were authored by this author
author.books = filterFilter(books, {author:author.id});

// Iterate each book and filter the comments by book ID
angular.forEach(books, function(book){
  book.comments = filterFilter(comments, {book:book.id});
});
```

Both of these have their own pros and cons.  The first makes it hard to manage the objects atomically which forces you to POST large objects and make the backend deal with updating the SQL database.  The second adds more work to the client because you need to pull down large datasets and then filter/join them to other models on the fly.

Is there another option that I have yet to come across or are one of these 2 ways considered best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with a team on a large-scale angular app and we have tried out both of those implementations.

We started out with linking on the front-end. Mostly because we didn't have a clear understanding of how we wanted to structure the data or in some cases even relate it. Creating highly generic resources and linking on the client seemed more flexible in the beginning.

We just recently moved to maintaining object structure on both ends of serialization, coming out of the rest API and going back into it. This has honestly taken loads of messy logic and murky relationships off of our plate, and I highly recommend it if your data is just basic objects you need to CRUD against. It also is highly maintainable and easy to build integration tools around.

An example:

If I request an author resource, I get the following data:

```
{
            'id':1,
            'firstName':'John',
            'lastName':'Steinbeck',
            'books':[{
               'id':123,
               'title': 'Grapes of Wrath',
               'author':1,
               'comments':[{
                   'id':555,
                   'content':'This is a great book!',
                   'book':123
               }]
            }]
        }
```

We go through and wrap each nested layer of data with [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). Restangular abstracts wrapping the objects as a RESTful resource in an awesome way.

We can then edit underlying objects with stuff like `firstAuthor.books[0].remove()`. Or build custom endpoints suing those objects that make it easy to update against, for example `Restangular.one('books', firstAuthor.books[0]).get()`.

One huge 'product' benefit of moving that direction is less API calls / better performance in the browser. When we were linking in Angular, I had one page that would make 50 API calls for an unusually complex object, and then still have to perform all the logic in the client. With nested serialization its been reduced to 1 API call and 10x better performance on that page.

A small thing --- it helped standardize how the backend deals with foreign keys. Instead of having weird attribute names for objects we know will be foreign keys (like appending _id to the attribute for the server) the server looks for that attribute and grabs its id. In the case of Python/Django, where book_comment is a foreign key:

```
book_comment = request.DATA["book_comment"]["id"]
```